# CORS config for s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have put a lot of files on my s3 and trying to configure CORS on my s3 bucket to access it, but every time it's showing me the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mylink.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have tried a bunch of settings but not able to hit the right set of xml policy.

here is the current one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
        <CORSRule>
            <AllowedOrigin>http://mylink.com</AllowedOrigin>
            <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
            <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
            <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
        </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Is static website hosting enabled on bucket?

Comment: Start with `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`.